# best method to delete a type cast pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have create a function 
that deallocates the memory of an 
object that points to a base class.

Regarding a field variable
the object can be typed cast
to one of the derived classes 
(DerA,DerB,DerC).

What is the best practice to delete
the object.

```
delete object;
delete (DerA*)obj;
delete static_cast<DerA>(object)
```

or all of the above do the same work.

A sample of my code looks like

```
void deal(BaseClass *obj)
{
   if(obj)
   {
      switch(obj->m_id)
      {
         case DerivedAObj:
         {
             delete (DerA*)obj;
             break;
         }
         case DerivedBObj:
         {
             delete static_cast<DerA>(obj);
             break;
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The 1st version is sufficient. No need for casting.

Comment: delete object ... by making sure the destructor of your base class is virtual.  By doing so, it will call the appropriate dtor...

Comment: ...**iff** the destructor was declared `virtual` in the base.

Comment: The best practice is to define a virtual destructor :-)

Comment: better: don't use raw owning pointers, that's rule number one in C++.

Comment: and don't reinvent `virtual` functions using `switch`. It's not likely to be any better, faster, or whatever. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Also, the target type of your `static_cast` is (A) wrong and (B) not qualified as a pointer. That wouldn't work at all. But if you ever genuinely need a cast, you should use the corrected `static_cast` syntax instead of the C-style cast. But you don't need it here.

Answer (score 5):

A solution is to make the destructor virtual. That way the destructor call through the base pointer is dispatched dynamically, and the correct child class destructor will be run. No casting needed.

---

> What is the best practice to delete the object.
>
> ```
> delete object;
> ```

This is the best way (of the options shown, see below for better). But it requires the virtual destructor in the base.

> ```
> delete (DerA*)obj;
> ```

This is correct even if the base destructor is not virtual. Some prefer `static_cast<DerA*>(object)` since that is more explicit. Both are equivalent.

> ```
> delete static_cast<DerA>(object)
> ```

You cannot delete non-pointers. This might work if `DerA` is implicitly convertible to `DerA*`. Otherwise it is ill-formed.

---

Even better than any of your options is to use a smart pointer. When you don't need shared ownership and when the destructor is virtual, you can use `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>`. When the unique pointer goes out of scope, the pointed object is automatically destroyed without an explicit `delete`.

If you need shared ownership, or if the destructor can not be virtual, you can use `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` instead.

Comment: And certainly no `switch`/`case` reinvention of `virtual` functions. :S